# Listar un directorio en Java mediante sockets (cliente/servidor)

Tags: java, socket

Estoy comenzando a utilizar sockets en Java y parece que todavía no los comprendo del todo. Estoy tratando de crear un servidor que espere en un puerto a que un cliente se conecte a él y que en el momento que dicho cliente se conecte mande un listado de un directorio.

El código que he estado probando hasta ahora sin mucho éxito es el siguiente:

**Servidor:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket servidor;
        Socket socket;
        try{
            servidor=new ServerSocket(5005);
            while(true){
                socket=servidor.accept();
                System.out.println("Ha llegado un cliente");
                OutputStream flujoSalida=socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(flujoSalida);

                InputStream flujoEntrada=socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(flujoEntrada);
                //Lectura y listado del directorio
                String sDirectorio = "./";
                File f = new File(sDirectorio);
                File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();
                for (int x=0;x<ficheros.length;x++){
                  dos.writeUTF(ficheros[x].getName());
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Cliente**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Cliente {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       InetAddress direccion;
        Socket servidor;
        try{
           direccion=InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
           servidor=new Socket(direccion,5005);
           DataInputStream datos=new DataInputStream(servidor.getInputStream());
           String mensaje=datos.readLine();
           System.out.println(mensaje);
           servidor.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

No consigo que el servidor mande un listado de los ficheros de un directorio al cliente.

¿Alguien podría iluminarme un poco el camino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el servidor:

```
 while(true){
     servidor=new ServerSocket(5005); <- Aqui esta el error
     socket=servidor.accept();
     ...
 }
```

> Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Al crear el servidor dentro del `while` con `new ServerSocket(5005)` después de aceptar un cliente vuelve a crear una instancia de `ServerSocket` con un puerto ya existente.

---

EDITADO

Para que funcione tu ejemplo, debes cambiar en el **Cliente**:

```
String mensaje=datos.readLine();
```

Por esto:

```
String ficheros = datos.readUTF();
```

---

Ahora vamos a ver como estas listando los ficheros:

Tú **Servidor**

```
String sDirectorio = "./";
File f = new File(sDirectorio);
File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();
for (int x=0;x<ficheros.length;x++){
     dos.writeUTF(ficheros[x].getName());
}
```

Cada ejecución en el servidor de `dos.writeUTF(ficheros[x].getName())` necesitas en el **cliente** `datos.readUTF()` para leer el contenido.

---

La pregunta es ¿conocemos el número de ficheros que va a contener un directorio? Entonces no sabemos cuantos `datos.readUTF();` debemos colocar en el cliente. Para esto se me ocurre 2 soluciones:

1 - Solución:
**Servidor**

```
String sDirectorio = "./";
String listadoFicheros = "";
File f = new File(sDirectorio);
File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();

for (int x=0;x<ficheros.length;x++){
     if(listadoFicheros.equals("")) {
        listadoFicheros = ficheros[x].getName();
     } else {
        listadoFicheros = listadoFicheros + ";" + ficheros[x].getName();
     }

 }
 dos.writeUTF(listadoFicheros);//<- "directorio1;directorio2;directorio3"
```

**Cliente**

```
String ficheros = datos.readUTF();
System.out.println(ficheros);//Listado de ficheros
String files[] = ficheros.split(";");//Separamos el string con ";"
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(i+" "+files[i]);
}
```

Las ventajas de enviar la información así es que solo hacemos un envío del Servidor al Cliente, lo malo es que debemos tratar la información al enviar y recibir.

---

2 - Una solución más cercana a tu planteamiento.

**Servidor**

```
String sDirectorio = "./";
File f = new File(sDirectorio);
File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();
dos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ficheros.length));//Numero de elementos
for (int x=0;x<ficheros.length;x++){                  
     dos.writeUTF(ficheros[x].getName());
}
```

**Cliente**

```
int numeroFicheros = Integer.parseInt(datos.readUTF());

for (int i = 0; i < numeroFicheros; i++) {
      System.out.println(datos.readUTF());
}
```

La ventaja de hacerlo de esta manera es que no tratamos la información, y la desventaja es que realizamos varios envíos por socket.

Comment: Buena, me quedo con la solución 1. Sólo plantearía un cambio, separar los nombres de los ficheros con "\n" en lugar de ";" en el servidor, se podrán imprimir de una vez en el cliente, sin tener que generar un array y usar otro bucle, y sigues teniendo la opción de obtener el array con ellos si fuera necesario.

Answer (score -1):

```
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Significa que alguna otra aplicación ya se está escuchando en el puerto de la aplicación actual está tratando de obligar.

lo que hay que hacer es, ya sea el puerto para su aplicación actual o mejor acabar de descubrir la aplicación que ya se está ejecutando y matarlo.

En **Linux** se puede encontrar el **pid** aplicación mediante:

```
netstat -tulpn
```